# How to prevent Stripe CardNumberElement reset in React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, stripe-payments

I have a React component where I'm using Stripe Elements to create a payment method. However, when I call the setIsSaving function(to update state), the CardNumberElement values are reset, and I'm encountering an error: "IntegrationError: We could not retrieve data from the specified Element. Please make sure the Element you are attempting to use is still mounted."

I'd like to know how I can prevent the CardNumberElement from being reset and keep the typed-in value in the Stripe card element while updating the isSaving state. Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  useStripe,
  useElements,
  CardNumberElement,
  CardCvcElement,
  CardExpiryElement
} from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";

export default function App() {
  const [isSaving, setIsSaving] = useState(false);
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();

  const handleSave = async () => {
    setIsSaving(true);
    // creating payment method
    const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardNumberElement);
    const result = await stripe.createPaymentMethod({
      type: "card",
      card: cardElement,
      billing_details: {
        name: "Joe Doe"
      }
    });

    // other code
  };
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSave}>
        <div>Please Type Card Number</div>
        <CardNumberElement />
        <div>Expiration date</div>
        <CardExpiryElement />
        <div>CVC</div>
        <CardCvcElement />
        <button type="submit">{isSaving ? "Loading" : "Save"}</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to ensure that the CardNumberElement retains the typed-in value even when setIsSaving is called. Any help or guidance on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stripe-zhqfvm?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Is it possible to replicate this code on some online IDE's like **[code-sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)**? Usually becomes difficult to identify the issue just by looking at the code

Comment: @mandy8055, edited the post to add link to codesandbox, but I'm not sure it will actually display the same error in the codesandbox as I used some random stripe key, but all the inputs are reset when isSaving is set

Comment: [`e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) can be used at the beginning of `handleSave()` to prevent the page and card element being reset